# Insert rows in a table

Tags: sql, select, insert

I have a table with three columns : row, col, value. This is sparse matrix with the following values:

```
Row-1 : 0, 1, 10
Row-2 : 0, 3, 5
```

The question is, how can I loop using select statement to insert missing row and column with values 0?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: sqllite3 to do a few assignments.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of all columns and of all rows, you can do:

```
insert into sparse (row, col, value)
    select r.row, c.col, 0
    from (select distinct row from sparse) r cross join
         (select distinct col from sparse) c left join
         sparse s
         on s.row = r.row and s.col = c.col
    where s.row is null;
```

This version assumes that each row and col has at least one value.

Comment: Thank you very much. There is a small typo, the last condition is s.col=c.col.